# Angular 5- link from REST API / JSON

Tags: json, angular, rest, api

```
<p>{{ project._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'].media_details?.sizes.medium_large.source_url }}</p>
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined

I got rid of the same error for 'sizes' by using the question mark on 'media_details', but how can I do the same on '_embedded'?

Comment: project?._embedded?['wp:featuredmedia']

Comment: Parser Error: Conditional expression project?._embedded?['wp:featuredmedia'].media_details?.sizes.medium_large.source_url  requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression

Comment: The '?' on projects is unneccesary, i was just testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by not passing it an undefined object.

```
<div *ngIf="project._embedded">
    <p>{{ project._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'].media_details?.sizes.medium_large.source_url }}</p>
</div>
```